# NodeJS Client OnBeforeUnload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to have a real-time game going, and I have the login nice and asynchronous, but I'm worried about the logout part. Often times, somebody will just close the browser window/tab instead of actually clicking the logout button.

Can NodeJS detect the `onbeforeunload` event so I can run a query to set them as offline?

I was thinking about just adding a "lastaction" timestamp but that would require almost constant refreshing, and a one-time logout check would be ideal.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` cannot be relied on.

Comment: No it can't, there's no way to detect browser events on the serverside, and doing ajax requests on beforeunload is notoriously unreliable. You'll have to use a "heartbeat" or timed logout.

Comment: @adeneo could I trigger a websocket response using a client side `onbeforeunload` or is it unreliable as bjb568 said?

Comment: If you're using something like socket.io it's already sending heartbeats, so you could just check if the connection was lost etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using web sockets, then the library you're using will probably support the socket disconnected event.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   // handle user connected

   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      // handle user disconnected
   });
});
```

Comment: This is correct.  If you're using socket.io, see the server example at the very end here if you want to see the exact syntax socket.io uses for the disconnect event: http://socket.io/#how-to-use